# JSP files are not created inside webapp folder of a maven web project

Tags: jsp, maven

I have created a maven web project from within eclipse using m2e plugin with artifactId `maven-archetype-webapp`. The project structure is like:

```
src  
    |--main  
        |--java  
        |--resources  
        |--webapp  
            |--index.jsp  
            |--WEB-INF
```

The body of the `index.jsp` is like a normal html without `<%@ page language="java".......>` tag.
The problem is when I try to create a new jsp file e.g. `login.jsp` inside webapp folder, it is not created there rather it automatically goes into or created inside:

```
target  
    |--m2e-wtp  
        |--web-resources  
            |--login.jsp  
            |--META-INF
```

How to resolve this situation ?How can I store jsp files in webapp folder ? Because of this when I deploy the .war file in tomcat and run the application, message comes: login.jsp is not found

Thanks

Comment: How do you create your file ?

Comment: @SamuelEUSTACHI Right click on `webapp->New->JSP File`

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue (Using Spring Tool Suite), apparently it's a fixed bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375605

Looks like it's scheduled to be fixed as of 3.4.2, I'm off to update mine now.

Comment: OK but I am using Eclipse Indigo SR2.So this bug shouldn't be there right ?Please share with me if you solve the problem.

Comment: It looks like the latest WTP build released is 3.4.1.  check out their WTP downloads page:

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/

I'm not sure when they've scheduled 3.4.2 for release.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new JSP from Eclipse (ctrl + N), the second step lets you select the destination folder.

[image]

Just select your webapp directory and go on.